# upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, nginx

Открываю страницу, получаю 500 ошибку. Смотрю логи, так такая ошибка

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

Страница грузится не больше 5 секунд. Все что нашел в гугле - надо увеличить тайм ауты, но они у меня по 1800 стоят.

Кто знает, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: а больше никаких ошибок не выдает?
Ошибка может быть в каких-то скриптах, например, которые очень долго обрабатываются.
на апаче это можно поправить добавив строку `KeepAlive On` в `httpd.conf`.  В nginx понимаю только название, к сожалению)

Comment: нет, это единая ошибка. при том, что страница грузится не больше 5 секунд. у меня nginx+apache. может я могу как то использовать ваш вариант?

Comment: Если у Вас что-то убунту подобное, то проверьте настройки апача. `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`   И там строчку KeepAlive.

Comment: А еще может не хватать мощности самого сервера, как вариант. Возможно стоит посмотреть логи не только джинкса и апача, но и вообще системные. В таком случае там может быть сообщение типа - Out of memory

Comment: мощностей сервер вполне достаточно

Comment: @НиколайГабараев, добавил в настройки apache2 параметр KeepAlive On - не помогло

Comment: а что вообще на странице происходит в момент обращения к ней?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/v29pewZt3nnVam

Comment: не, это понятно. Я имею ввиду, что там происходит под капотом. Какие скрипты запускаются, что они делают и т.д.
Еще, возможно, какая-то ошибка в `.htaccess`

Comment: там происходит выборка с базы и вставка в новую таблицу. если убрать вконце $model->save() - ошибки нету, если вставить - есть. но по идее если ошибка yii2 - он должен был бы выдать ее

Comment: у вас связка nginx→apache→php? nginx сообщает, что apache разрывает связь. разбирайтесь с apache. начните с обращения непосредственно к нему (без посредничества nginx) и просмотра логов.